# Weaponized Riddles

Tags: riddle, story

Ian Peleaga was on a quest. It was said arms dealers had a huge operation here in southern Atlanta and as an FBI agent, it was his job to expose it.
He had traced some dealers to an abandoned house at the edge of Douglas. The crime boss had taken a liking to him and wanted him to follow them. Ian was puzzled as to why, but obviously, clues had been left behind for him.

Like this house. He and his team rummaged through all the drawers, shelves, and even the shower drain. *Nothing.*
Except for a cryptic note.

> The mathematician, RomanIan Douglas loved to **MIX** his coffee.

It was obvious it was meant for him. The strange uppercase I highlighting 'Ian'. Ian almost laughed.

But he never even *remotely liked* math. Why math? Eww, numbers. And *coffee*? He was more of a black tea person. And why was mix in caps and bolded on the note? Almost making a hole through the paper. This made no sense...

He was Romanian, his last name coming from one of the mountains there. And here he was in Douglas. But he guessed it the Douglas in the clue didn't mean *anything*.

He pondered this for hours. Then he took out his phone and googled a number and 2 words, one-word being *coffee*.

**He got a result.** Smiling to himself, he entered in his GPS `**** ****** *** S, *******, GA 31533`.

**What did he find out? What is the address?**

Interested?

- [Part 2: Dishing it out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110424/weaponized-riddles-2-dishing-it-out)

Comment: MIX in roman numerals is 1009.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address is:

> 1009 Coffee Ave S, Douglas, GA 31533

What he Googled:

> 1009 Douglas Coffee

Why?

> **GA 31533** points to a city called Douglas in Georgia, U.S. and **MIX** in Roman numerals (as hinted by the first name) stands for the number 1009.