# Weaponized Riddles 2: Dishing it out

Tags: riddle, word

Of course! MIX, 1009, Coffee, it all made sense! Arriving at 1009 Coffee Ave S, he walked into the house, finding the door slightly open. It was in pristine condition, just like the house he and his wife had bought.

[image: Image of a house]

Sitting on the couch, he picked up the note lying on the table. *This is a pretty clean house...wonder how much it goes for..maybe $750,000? Looks like the property is over an acr-* He pauses his train of thought, focusing on the note on hand.

*Oh, brother.*

> In the city of MMXVIII.
> A dish is served.
> How sweet is the Sig Sauer! _ _ _ _ _
> The victor is the key.

*These notes are starting to get plain cheesy.* Ian **did** have a Sig Sauer P365X handgun, it was one of his favorites, to be honest, but he wouldn't call it "Sweet".

He realized what it meant, and it clicked **too** well. He opened his laptop, retrieving it from his car, and set it upon the table. He booked the earliest ticket to the main airport of _____. He grinned to himself.
Stuffing the note inside his pocket, he felt something hard. Pulling it out, he found a key. *Weird.* Ian walked out of the house, but not before taking one more look at the house.

*Oh Boy.*

**Where did Ian go?**

Hint:

> Anagrams and Synonyms. And the name of that city, looks like some kind of numbers?  Also, no, the key in the story (at the back of the note) is not related to the key in the story.

Hint 2:

> You need 5 letter anagram for Sig Sauer. Also..you need a synonym for the dish..which is a bowl.

First time hearing about Ian Peleaga?

- [Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110416/weaponized-riddles)

Comment: You should really wait to add Hints.  It appears that this puzzle is relatively easy without them, but you should still allow users the time to figure it out first.  Then, if there are no responses, you can start to add more information.

Comment: Do the 5 `_` at the end of the third line indicate something?

Comment: Yeah. 5 letter anagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*In the city of MMXVIII.

A dish is served.*

> Those Roman numerals come to 2018, and the second hint tells us that "dish" = bowl. Could it be something to do with the [2018 Super Bowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_LII)? (I'm neither American nor interested in sports, so forgive me if this is way off making sense.)

*How sweet is the Sig Sauer! _ _ _ _ _

The victor is the key.*

> <s>The city of the MMXVIII dish (2018 Super Bowl) was Minneapolis, and the victors were the Philadelphia Eagles. That could mean the "key" (answer) is **Philadelphia**, although I haven't figured out how to factor in the Sig Sauer. The only 5-letter anagram of Sauer is *ureas*, which doesn't seem to connect with either Minneapolis or Philadelphia.</s>

Thanks to @MOehm for getting the final part of the puzzle:

> It doesn't quite make sense to anagram only "Sauer", but how to get a 5-letter anagram from the whole of "Sig Sauer"? Choosing five appropriate letters and using the hint of "sweet", we can find SUGAR. Putting this together with the other hints of 2018 and BOWL, we get the [2018 Sugar Bowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Sugar_Bowl), whose victors were the **Alabama** Crimson Tide. So presumably that's the key we're looking for, and Ian booked his flight to the [Birmingham-Shuttlesworth International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birmingham%E2%80%93Shuttlesworth_International_Airport).

Comment: Awesome answer. You're right about it being a bowl football game. And yes, 2018.
And yes, the winner of the said bowl game is the answer, not the city of the bowl game.

You're actually looking for the anagram of Sig Sauer, or rather..sigsauer. You're really close to the answer, and you've completed the answer. Try to get the right answer, and I can accept this answer. Good luck!

Comment: @WhipStreak23 But how can an anagram of sigsauer be a 5-letter word? That's what's puzzling me ...

Comment: It's all very loose, even with the heavy hints. I guess we are supposed to take five letters from the rack to get a [sweet dish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Sugar_Bowl). (That's a thing? The things you learn about on PSE!)

Comment: Haha, well done. Now does someone want to answer it now? lol, the bounty closes in 4 hours.

Yeah it is pretty loose, but I'm new at this, so live and learn.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks, that makes sense! TIL too :-) Hope you don't mind me incorporating your comment into my answer.